# PHP Make SOAP Client Request Returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm using PHP to make SOAP request. I do have information of the web service from the third party. Basically what they have give me:

1. The full URI request ( http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxxx/some/services/BasicDo )
2. Username & Password

I am pretty new however I could understand a bit how PHP SOAP things work. However in the example I found the URL called is something like `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/services/myservice?wsdl` which is not really same with what I have with me. Additional question here is what should I ask them? Perhaps what is the name of wsdl file?

Also so far I have this code with me:

```
try{
    $client = new SoapClient("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/some/services/BasicDo?wsdl", array('login'=>"myusername",'password'=> "mypwd"));
}
catch(SoapFault $fault) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

But from the console, I received status 500 Internal Server Error. I don't know how this can be, I am expecting something from the catch block. Somebody please clarify me this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this??? I'm having almost exactly the same issue. My SOAP call worked fine one day then suddenly stopped and started returning the 500 internal server error the next. If you managed to figure this out I'd love to hear how?

Comment: You may have already done this but did you try going to the address "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/some/services/BasicDo?wsdl" in your browser to make sure you are getting a valid wsdl (xml) file back?

Comment: Hi Mark, so update. I've just taken the site with the problem and set it up locally on my machine running on MAMP PRO with near the exact same version of PHP for the site. In fact the local copy of the site is running 5.4.34 and the production site is running on 5.4.39. But miraculously the SOAP call is working fine. Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Are you sure the SOAP service url starts with http and not https? If it's the latter, then I have some troubleshooting ideas

Comment: Have you looked into the `error.log` of your server/vhost? There should be a message what went wrong. If you like to see the errors on screen use the php.ini option `display_errors` with `on` and set the `error_reporting` in you script to `E_ALL`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it seems like [no matter what you try](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gqng-j109) (e.g. passing `array('exceptions' => 0)`, `SoapClient()` will throw an uncatchable E_ERROR on network connection issues. This bug is still present as high up as PHP 5.5.4 ([REF](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65779)).

Summary:

Test script:

```
$client=@new SoapClient('garbage',array('exceptions'=>FALSE));
echo 'OK';
```

Expected result: We should see "OK",

Actual result:

If we use `register_shutdown_function` to display the contents of `error_get_last()`,  we get:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 1
    [message] => SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'garbage' : failed 
to load external entity "garbage"
)
```

To explain why you suddenly get this error without changing anything on your system, and to explain why SoapClient works on your local machine and not on your production system, it is most likely a **firewall** issue.

Here is what another [person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494910/soapclient-or-fopen-not-working) reported that solved his problem:

> I solved my problem. It was actually an issue with my firewall. The
>   firewall was dropping packets sent via PHP, but via curl or wget were
>   not being dropped. I added a rule for all traffic from that server and
>   increased the packet drop length and everything is working great now!

### Advice:

My best advice at this time to write some code in the same PHP file that checks if the SOAP service url resolves and loads properly *before* calling the SoapClient.

Comment: Hello UserProg, were you able to verify if firewall settings were causing your issue? I hope this answer could shed light on this pesky issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add these codes at head of the file to see where the error happen

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the issue may be but I did the following to debug this issue when I encountered it

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/some/services/BasicDo?wsdl", array('login'=>"myusername",'password'=> "mypwd"));
```

Things you can do:

1. Create a PHP file. Name it anything. Write the following code there:

   ini_set('display_errors','On');

   $client = new SoapClient("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/some/services/BasicDo?wsdl", array('login'=>"myusername",'password'=> "mypwd"));
   var_dump($client);
   exit;
2. Run the file.
3. Chances are this will show you the required exception.

In my case, Our server used a proxy which I had not passed in the parameters due to which I was getting the issue.
Let us know how it goes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure you have access to the SOAP server.

From the machine that is running your php script try to access the wsdl file and check if it is valid.

you can for example use `wget http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/some/services/BasicDo?wsdl` then open the saved file and see what you are getting. Is it a valid wsdl?

Once you have sorted out our access, then you need to read the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php). You may need to authenticate differently or pass other options.

As for why the catch block is not picking up your exception, you are only catching `SoapFault`. The 500 internal server error can be caused by anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've just looked into our php.ini file on our shared hosting package and allow_url_fopen is disabled. Is it actually possible to perform a SOAP call without having allow_url_fopen turned on? However this SOAP service was working previously so unless allow_url_fopen was only just disabled I don't know we could of been making SOAP with it turned off all this time. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate all of the answers given. I am actually working with another party which I don't have any access on the remote side. My job is to make SOAP request to the server. However it turned out that there is NO web service available for me. So I ended up using cURL to send raw POST of SOAP request. :-)